# iOS project works on iPhone but not in simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

Bonjour,

My iOS project support landscape and run perfectly on my iPhone 4s 7.1.2 but not in the simulator.

Here some screenshot :

[iPhone Landscape](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/321839IMG0151.png)

[Simulator Landscape](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/353334Capturede769cran20150116a768235554.png)

Both screenshots have been taken in landscape mode and the simulator does not seem to resize the board correctly

Here the code I use to change orientation.

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];

        int width = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width - [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.width - 10;
        int height = width;

        int x = 5;
        int y = ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width / 2) - (width / 2);

        [board setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
    }];
}
else {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
        [board setFrame:CGRectMake(0, [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width)];
    }];
}
```

}

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Have you set breakpoints to see what values you're getting?

Comment: As far as I know, willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation is not working on simulator, because it's triggered by the acceleration sensor of the iPhone device. Obviously, the simulator doesn't have one.

Comment: You can on the iOS Simulator -> Hardware -> Rotate Left / Rotate Right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried your code but I strongly believe what you see is caused by the **deprecated API**. [Official documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:) gives details, and the new API that does what you want is [viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIContentContainer_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIContentContainer/viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:)

Also there are some other questions on stackoverflow like this talking about solutions: [willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation not called on ios6/7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20425607/willanimaterotationtointerfaceorientation-not-called-on-ios6-7)

Comment: You are right, willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration: is deprecated in iOS 8...

I tried viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator: it seem to works fine on the simulator.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad to help. Also, thanks for giving me an "Answer" mark and 1UP :)